# Cannot create new git branch in Heroku project

Tags: git, heroku, branch

I pulled a project from Heroku and now when I am trying to create in this project on my localhost a new branch, I always get this error message:

```
git checkout new_branch
error: pathspec 'new_branch' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

When I run `git branch -a`, I get

```
* master
  remotes/heroku/HEAD -> heroku/master
  remotes/heroku/master
```

What causing this error? And, how can I fix it?

Thank you

Comment: reading the doc before using the commands wouldn't hurt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to say `git checkout -b new_branch` to create the branch. See the documentation for checkout here:

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html